# Deterministic Wallet Step By Step

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, deterministic-wallets

I'm reading about `deterministic wallets`, I get the point, but it get's confusing when you actually start setting up things. I have to install support for generating "whatever"-coin addresses on a server. Where do I start, how should it be done? People are talking about importing keys from a seed. OK great but again, how? People talk about using different wallets. Should I use one of the existing wallets? How can I create my own wallet? Is there a console-based step by step tutorial that you can apply to any crypto-coin network/wallet?

Currently I use `bitcoind` for communicating with bitcoin network. It's the only good-enough documented piece of code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bitcoin Armory is the longest standing deterministic wallet project as far as I know. You can take a look at their implementation and move on from there. Armory also uses bitcoind to communicate with the network.

Answer (score -2):

If you know Python, [pycoin](https://github.com/richardkiss/pycoin) might be a good place to start for a hd wallet implementation.